# Why is this workstation attempting to log on to a decommissioned DC?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016

The primary symptom in this case was the user reporting "Slow logon". Indeed, it would take about 40 seconds for the workstation to log in to Windows. Enabling the DNS Client log in event viewer and logging out and back in revealed an interesting clue: At the beginning of the logon, the workstation would query DNS for an old domain controller.

Back story: The old domain controller was 2008r2 and upgraded about 4 months ago to Server 2016. The old server was then demoted and decommissioned.

Somehow, it looks like this workstation didn't get the memo and still thinks that the old DC is valid and tries to log into it. Because an old DNS entry for the old server was not cleaned up, the DNS query resolves and the workstation then waits 30s for the login attempt to time out before trying the new DC. The new DC, of course, works jut fine and logs in immediately.

We can work around this by deleting that old entry in DNS and flushing the workstation's DNS client cache, but my question is why is the workstation still querying for the old DC in the first place?

My concern is that this may point to some missing or incorrect configuration in AD or in our server decommission process. A few things I noted while looking into this:

- The old server's DNS address was removed once while troubleshooting similar "slowness". The DNS entry was back, but dated before the decom so I can only assume that it was missed.
- The old server's lingering DNS record was just the A record. All SRV and _msdcs records were removed at the time of decom.
- AD Sites & Services had not been set up. The old server of course was clear, but no subnets had been configured. In a small business with one site, one DC, and one subnet, this isn't usually a problem. I created the subnet anyway.
- The workstation logs in fine as soon as the attempt to connect to the old server times out. There are no event log errors related to logon failures or DC failures or Group Policy failures.*emphasized text*
- Rejoining the workstation to the domain can solve the problem by getting the workstation back on track (vs working around it by cleaning DNS), but I'd rather identify why the workstation didn't get the memo so that we don't have to rejoin workstations to the domain every time we upgrade a DC.

Comment: The DNS client queries DNS for a DC. If DNS returns a DC that no longer exists then it isn't a client problem. As you stated, DNS records for the old DC still existed. Go through DNS and confirm that any and all A, CNAME, and SRV records for the old DC no longer exist.

Comment: @joeqwerty - I should clarify, the only DNS entry that remained was an A record. SRV & _msdcs records were all cleaned up during decom.

Comment: `The old domain controller was 2008r2 and upgraded about 4 months ago to Server 2019. The old server was then demoted and decommissioned.` - What do you mean by that? There's no direct in-place upgrade path from 2008R2 to 2019. Do you mean that you replaced this DC with a Windows Server 2019 DC?

Comment: Was the old DC also acting as an AD DNS server? It sounds like the client has the old DC/DNS server IP configured in its TCP/IP DNS settings. Either statically or from DHCP.

Comment: @joeqwerty - sorry lol my bad, it was upgraded to 2016. Yay typos. We've been doing a lot of 2019 upgrades in the last couple months so I've got 2019 on the brain.

Comment: @twconnell - Old DC was AD DNS & DHCP. New DC is AD DNS & DHCP. DHCP server & scope options have the new server's IP for DNS. Workstation is using DHCP and has the correct DNS server assigned by DHCP.

Comment: Check the workstation secure channel with the domain with nltest.exe /sc_query:<domain name>. There could be something in the registry of that workstation pointing to the old server. But if rejoining the domain fixes the problem, and this happens to 1% of the clients, it may not be worth the effort.

Comment: @twconnell - 
`Flags: 30 HAS_IP  HAS_TIMESERV 
Trusted DC Name \\NewDomainController.example.com 
Trusted DC Connection Status Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
The command completed successfully`
Note on this workstation I did run `Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair`
and `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword` on this workstation in hopes that'd repair the domain connection without having to rejoin it to the domain. Other workstations have the same results. I'm willing to accept it was a fluke on the workstation, but I'm still anxious there might have been a problem with the decom & upgrade.

Comment: If you're worried about the DC changes, you should perform an AD health check. Try this in your environment: https://evotec.xyz/what-do-we-say-to-health-checking-active-directory/